# XML Architecture

Tags: c#, .net, xml

For my application I have to use a undefined number of different detection strategies. A strategy is defined in the following fashion:

[image]

The AND gate can also be a OR gate. For now, I hard coded all these rules in my code. For better extensability, I'd like to define all the detection startegies respectively rules in a XML file and parse it. But I'm not really sure how I can define such a detection strategy in a XML file. Any hints how to start?

Comment: Not an answer as such, but as you are using .Net you could look into using Microsoft Workflow Foundation. This sort of thing is exactly what it is designed for.

Comment: looks like Specification pattern

Comment: @Guy: Thanks, but isn't this a little bit an overkill for this quite simple problem?

Comment: @Arseny: Thanks, but nevertheless the problem of specifiying the rules in a generic and extensible way is still there?

Comment: It is yes, but I guess that depends if this is your whole problem or if you have simplified it for us. Further, if the specification changes and suddenly you need to add more rules or metrics or whatever, WF would probably handle all those cases, whereas you would still have to extend your XML solution yourself.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Can they get any more complicated than in your diagram?

If not, something like the below, which just translates the structure of your diagram into

```
<Strategy>
    <Name>Test-1</name>
    <Quality-problem>Too much splurge in the windler<Quality-problem>
    <Gate type="AND">
       <Left>
           <Metric>foo</Metric>
           <Comparison>less-than</Comparison>
           <Threshold>100</Threshhold>
       </Left>
       <Right>
           <Metric>bar</Metric>
           <Comparison>greater-than</Comparison>
           <Threshold>200</Threshhold>
       </Right>
    </Gate>
</Strategy>
```

If they do get more complex, you can still use something like the above, just a little more complex. You can/shuld write a XML schema  to describe what you come up with so you can use standard validation tools, validating parsers etc.

Comment: Thanks, this seems nice. And yes it can be get more complicated, but not too complicated. No more than 3 or 4 gates and 1-2 depths levels.

Comment: OK, so make Left and Right be either a gate or metric and you can represent nested structures

Answer (score 4):

Look at RuleML http://ruleml.org/

> RuleML (Rule Markup Language) is a
>   unifying family of XML-serialized rule
>   languages spanning across all
>   industrially relevant kinds of Web
>   rules. It accommodates and extends
>   other recent rule languages, building
>   interoperation bridges between them.
>   The Specification of RuleML is
>   currently being developed from Version
>   0.91 to Version 1.0.

also

> The goal of the Rule Markup Initiative
>   is to develop RuleML as the canonical
>   Web language for rules using XML
>   markup, formal semantics, and
>   efficient implementations.
>
> RuleML covers the entire rule
>   spectrum, from derivation rules to
>   transformation rules to reaction
>   rules. RuleML can thus specify queries
>   and inferences in Web ontologies,
>   mappings between Web ontologies, and
>   dynamic Web behaviors of workflows,
>   services, and agents.

This should avoid you reinventing the wheel. Also the XML is only part of it, if you roll your own you also have to build the toolkit.

EDIT:
Also look at Drools (Java-specific) http://www.jboss.org/drools

Comment: @Paul I'd also expect some of the languages to be engineered like 1970's battletanks, but at least one should review what's already been done

Comment: Yes, I wasn't dissing your idea of looking at that website - as you say, part or all of this particular wheel may have already been invented

Answer (score 2):

If I have understood the problem you could make an XML file with this structure:

```
<root>
    <rules>
        <rule name="rule1" value="METRIC 1 > ThreShold 1" />
        <rule name="rule2" value="METRIC 2 > ThreShold 2" />
    </rules>
    <connectors>
        <port type="AND">
            <value name="rule1" />
            <value name="rule2" />
        </port>
    </connectors>
</root>
```

And then parse it with LINQ.

### Port Class

```
class Port
{
    public PortType Type 
    { 
        get;
        set; 
    }

    public IEnumerable<Rule> Rules 
    { 
        get; 
        set;
    }

    public Port(PortType type, IEnumerable<Rule> rules)
    {
        this.Type = type;
        this.Rules = rules ?? Enumerable.Empty<Rule>();
    }
}

enum PortType
{
    AND,
    OR
}
```

### Rule Class

```
class Rule : IEquatable<Rule>
{
    public string Value 
    { 
        get; 
        set;
    }

    public string Name 
    { 
        get;
        set; 
    }

    public Rule(string name, string value)
    {
        this.Name = name;
        this.Value = value;
    }

    public bool Equals(Rule other)
    {
        return this.Name == other.Name;
    }

    public override int GetHashCode()
    {
        return this.Name.GetHashCode();
    }
}
```

### LINQ

```
        XDocument document = XDocument.Parse(xml);
        XElement root = document.Root;

        var rules = from rule in root.Element("rules").Elements()
                    let name = rule.Attribute("name").Value
                    let value = rule.Attribute("value").Value
                    select new Rule(name, value);

        var ports = from port in root.Elements("connectors").Elements()
                    let portType = (PortType)Enum.Parse(typeof(PortType), port.Attribute("type").Value)
                    let portRules = from rule in port.Elements()
                                    let name = rule.Attribute("name").Value
                                    select new Rule(name, null)
                    select new Port(portType, rules.Intersect(portRules));
```

**EDIT:** If you need to parse rule value you can just expand value attribute in XML and then parsing it with LINQ.

Answer (score 1):

Two possiblies come to mind:

1 - Are the rules only comparing numeric values? In that case Xml could work.

```
<Rules>
<Rule name="MyRule" left="3" operation=">" right="1" />
</Rules>
```

2 - You could also define a class that
    stores your detection strategies.
    Once you've discovered all the
    strategies simply serialize the
    class and save it to the file-system
    or a database.

Answer (score 1):

There exist standards for this kind of thing, like [XCL](http://standards.iso.org/ittf/PubliclyAvailableStandards/c039175_ISO_IEC_24707_2007%28E%29.zip). Does look like a bit of overkill though.

Comment: Did you mean to point to a licence document? http://standards.iso.org/ittf/licence.html

Comment: The link is to a PDF. You'll be intercepted and have to click Accept.